# JComboBox not reacting to setSelectedItem method

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Overview:
When the `Day` fields `start` or `end` of the `DayPeriod` class change, combo boxes (i.e. one for each field) are to react to this, showing the String delivered by the `toString()` method of the fields.

Problem:
Although the combos' `getSelectedItem()` and `getSelectedIndex()` confirm that a change has taken place after the `setSelectedItem` method was used, it is not visible, i.e. the old selections remain visible.

Details:
The `DayPeriod` class contains the private `Day start` and `Day end` fields and their respective setters, implementing a `PropertyChangeListener`.

```
public class DayPeriod implements PropertyChangeListener {

    private Day                     start, end;
    private PropertyChangeSupport   propertyChangeSupport;                      

    DayPeriod () {
        setStart(new Day());
        setEnd(new Day());
        propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
        addPropertyChangeListener(this);
    }

    void setStart (Day newDay) {
        Day oldDay = start;
        start = newDay;
        try {
            propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("dayStart", oldDay, start);
        }
        catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        }
    }

    void setEnd (Day day) {
        Day oldDay = end;
        end = day;
        try {
            propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("dayEnd", oldDay, end);
        }
        catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        }
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener (PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange (PropertyChangeEvent event) { // listener
        if (event.getPropertyName().equals("dayStart")) {
            Day day = (Day) event.getNewValue();
            if (getEnd().compareTo(day) < 0)
                setEnd(day);
        }
    }
}
```

The `propertyChange` method at the end is just to make sure that when `start` gets changed, `end` gets changed if its value is less than `start`'s, i.e. a period cannot end before it starts.

The `Day` class is pretty much just about weekdays. It implements the `equals(Day other)` method, the `Comparable` interface, and the `toString()` method; all working as expected.

```
public class Day implements Comparable<Day> {

    private DayOfWeek dayOfWeek;

    Day () {
        dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.MONDAY;
    }

    Day (DayOfWeek day) {
        dayOfWeek = day;
    }

    public String toString () {
        return dayOfWeek.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, OpeningHours.locale);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo (final Day other) {
        if (getDayOfWeek().compareTo(other.getDayOfWeek()) < 0)
            return -1;
        else if (getDayOfWeek().compareTo(other.getDayOfWeek()) > 0)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    DayOfWeek getDayOfWeek () {
        return dayOfWeek;
    }

    boolean equals (Day other) {
        return getDayOfWeek().equals(other.getDayOfWeek());
    }
}
```

Here come the combo boxes:
My instances of the `DayCombo` class (`extends JComboBox`), created in a panel, also have a `propertyChange` method, so they can react whenever the events mentioned above fire.
In the constructor, a combo box is filled with all possible days, and it adds itself to the period that it is to watch.

```
public class DayCombo extends JComboBox<Day> implements ItemListener, PropertyChangeListener {

    private DayPeriod period;
    private boolean isStart;

    {
        for (DayOfWeek day : DayOfWeek.values())
            addItem(new Day(day));
        addItemListener(this);
    }

    DayCombo (DayPeriod period, boolean isStart) {
        this.period = period;
        this.isStart = isStart;
    }

    public void itemStateChanged (final ItemEvent e) {
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            Day selectedDay = (Day) getSelectedItem();

            if (isStart)
                period.setStart(selectedDay);
            else
                period.setEnd(selectedDay);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange (PropertyChangeEvent event) {
        Day selectedDay = (Day) getSelectedItem();
        Day otherDay = (Day) (event.getNewValue());
        String propertyName = event.getPropertyName();

        if (!isStart && propertyName.equals("dayStart")) {
            // main focus, not working as expected
            setSelectedItem(otherDay);
        }
    }
}
```

I guess this is less about any listeners but more about the combo boxes not refreshing the visible.

Please let me know if more comments inside the code are desired.